# How to enable user site without `setup.py` when installing a Python package?

Tags: python

**How to enable user site without `setup.py`?**

I would like to install a Python package on a Linux server in **editable** mode:

```sh
cd package_name
pip install --user -e .
```

The above command requires user site to be enabled (otherwise it will produce an error). Previously this can be done by adding the following line in `setup.py`:

```py
import site
site.ENABLE_USER_SITE = True
```

However, recently it has been [officially recommended](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#configuring-metadata)  to use a `setup.cfg` file instead of `setup.py` for configuring metadata.

My question is how to enable user site in this case.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The `site` module isn't related to your package's metadata. I'm not sure why you thought it was. Changes to `site` only impact the currently running interpreter.

Comment: For what it's worth, `site.ENABLE_USER_SITE` will only be `False` when python is invoked with the [`-s`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-s) flag or when [`PYTHONNOUSERSITE`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONNOUSERSITE) is set. If you want the user site directory, there's a good chance that you just need to _not_ use one of those.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for your comments. I was not thinking that `site` was related to the metadata. Actually my question has nothing to do with metadata, sorry if this was not clear. The question is simply how to enable user site when there's no `setup.py` (I've updated it to make this clear). Regarding your second comment: I do need to explicitly enable user site for it to work (probably because the admin of my server disabled it by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editable installs without a `setup.py` file are not currently supported by setuptools. From the [latest setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#development-mode):

> `setuptools` allows you to install a package without copying any files to your interpreter directory (e.g. the site-packages directory). This allows you to modify your source code and have the changes take effect without you having to rebuild and reinstall. This is currently incompatible with PEP 517 and therefore it requires a `setup.py` script with the following content:
>
> ```py
> import setuptools
> setuptools.setup()
> ```

Do note that `setup.cfg` and `setup.py` are not mutually exclusive. If you need to do some dynamic configuration (like modifying `site.ENABLE_USER_SITE`) during installation, then that's expressly what `setup.py` currently does.

Comment: Thanks! I replaced `setup.cfg` with `setup.py` in order to install the package (actually I posted the question only due to curiosity), but it's good to know that one can use `setup.py` on top of `setup.cfg`.